# Unable to run Kundera Sample application

Tags: kundera

I am unable to run a sample application using Kundera Sample.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: invalid persistence.xml
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceXMLLoader.getDocument(PersistenceXMLLoader.java:107)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceXMLLoader.findPersistenceUnits(PersistenceXMLLoader.java:142)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceUnitLoader.findPersistenceMetadatas(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:130)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceUnitLoader.getPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:78)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceUnitLoader.load(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:63)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.ApplicationLoader.load(ApplicationLoader.java:43)
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:95)
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:72)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.main.KunderaExample.main(KunderaExample.java:19)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1887)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceXMLLoader.getDocument(PersistenceXMLLoader.java:103)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This is related to loading remotel persistence.xsd from sun java site. Change this in your persistence.xml

> https://raw.github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/Kundera-2.0.4/kundera-core/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>     version="2.0">

2.0.6 release will also load it locally.

-Vivek